# How to zip a folder in osx excluding the "Icon" file?

Tags: macos, terminal, zip, google-drive

I have been trying to zip a folder using the terminal and excluding the Google Drive pesky "Icon" file.

This is the command I tried using:

```
zip my-zipped-folder.zip -r folder-to-zip/ -x "Icon" "*.DS_Store"

# Also tried \r and ^M
zip ... -x "Icon\r" "Icon^M"
```

For some reason excluding the .DS_Store file works, but excluding the Icon file does not.

**Does anybody know how to exclude the Icon file from the final zip?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `-x "Icon"` use `-x "*Icon*"`

Comment: Did you use strong quotes: ' or weak quotes: " ?

Comment: This works on my OS X box- `-x "*Icon*"`